# How often does the RSS widget get updates?

Tags: rss, memory, widgets

I am asking since I am trying to understand if this widget is causing my server to overuse CPU or memory.

But either way - it's interesting to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RSS widget uses [`fetch_feed()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/fetch_feed) function, which is setting default cache lifetime to 43200 seconds (12 hours).

Since this value is filtered it can be overridden (as can feed cache overall). I did encounter plugin once, whose developer citing *performance reasons* completely disabled feed caching for all feeds.

Comment: do you know if `fetch_feed()` uses transients?  If so memcached might improve the feed performance.

Comment: @Chris_O yes, it does use transients. Native SimplePie cache is files-based, but WP implementation changes that to `WP_Feed_Cache_Transient` class.